# User reauthentiction problom in firebase in react native

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I made a aap using firebase in react expo and authentication method is firebase email and password but problom is when user is already login and reopen the app the login page is open and not save the user authenticated data

I want try Asyc storage but still its not working and i want to its solution how to skip login page

Answer (score 0):

Without a bit of current code it is hard to understand how your code is structured, specially the auth part.

I will try to guess with some questions.

Are you using `authState` component?

Something like this:

```js
import { useAuthState } from "react-native-firebase-hooks/auth";
```

If not please do so.

You can then use it in code like so:

```js
 const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
```

Then you can identify login state with the following piece of code:

```js
if (!user) authenticateUser();
```

Where `authenticateUser()` function does sign the user in by email and password again.

If `user` exists, you can then proceed with the normal usage and flow of your application navigation.

There are a lot of examples at your disposal about using the `authState` component to manage the authentication state within react that will serve your purpose. You can always go search for some extra examples too. HTH!

Comment: For react-native (mobile) component, check out this link: https://github.com/bartkoedijk/react-native-firebase-hooks/tree/main/auth

Comment: For react (regular websites) component, check out this link: https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/auth